# Output of "ls > a.txt | wc" and "ls | wc" in the zsh shell

Tags: shell, zsh

Using the `zsh` shell, I observe the same output when I execute `ls > a.txt | wc` and `ls | wc`. Could someone confirm my understanding regarding the same.

In the first command the `STDOUT` is redirected to the file `a.txt` by usage of `>` operator and by making use of the pipe `STDOUT` (which currently points to the file) is redirected to the write end of the pipe, `wc` command reads from the pipe thus producing the same effect as `ls | wc`

But my doubt over here is that since I see the same output this means the output of ls is written to both the pipe and `a.txt` (I checked the file). Why should the output be written to both, as in when `ls` is executing the file descriptor `STDOUT` would be either pointing to the write end of the pipe or to the file, hence I shouldn't  be getting output in both.

Assuming I am in a directory with file which contains 2 files `a.txt` and `sample.txt` then

1. Running both the aforementioned commands gives output `2 2 17`
2. `a.txt` contains

```
a.txt 

sample.txt
```

Comment: Where do you run this code, and what shell are you using? My result is different on a Ubuntu 16 Bash. When I try the first command, the output of `ls` is in `a.txt`, and the output of `wc` is three zeros. The second command yields three numbers that are not zero. Can you edit the question and add the output of both commands and the content of `a.txt`?

Comment: Are you using zsh? If so, this is its [`MULTIOS` feature](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios).

Comment: Yes I am using zsh.

Comment: @berndbausch could you explain the reason for your output. As far as I understand the output in your case is written the file. In which case wc gets nothing resulting in the `0 0 0`. But even if nothing is written to the pipe shouldn't the terminal be blocked waiting for something to be written to the pipe which wc can read later, why is it displaying `0 0 0`

Comment: When `ls` is done, the pipe's input is closed, and `wc` gets an EOF.

Comment: Thanks a lot, makes sense.